# Any good svn strategy for Joomla site development?

Tags: svn, joomla, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have a running Joomla website and I would like to implement SVN for it.

Different from other website, Joomla is not 100% file based.  If it is a pure file based system, it can be easily managed with SVN.

Joomla has some database data change when installing and upgrading modules.  Everytime I have new component developed and installed to Joomla, recording the file base change is not enough.

Do anyone has good SVN strategy for Joomla site to keep track all ongoing development progress?

Comment: you mix backup and version-contol, while they are different things. Site-administration does not require VCS, only **detailed documenting** of all operations

Comment: Maybe I am not explaining my case detail enough.  I have a team and we will do component/module/plugin development concurrently.  Once a component is completed, it will be installed to Joomla as part of the system base.  Then when another teammate wants to checkout from SVN, I want him to have a most updated version of the core system (with the latest component installed).  I think people who has joomla experience will understand situation I am talking about.